# special point distance transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, euclidean-distance, binary-image

I use matlab to calculate the distance transform of a binary image, and I found that bwdist() can calculate distances of all the points of the image, but I just want to know the distance of a special point.
for example,I have a binary image like this

```
image =

     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
```

The bwdist() compute the distance transform of all points

```
>> bwdist(a)

ans =

         0    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000         0
    2.0000    1.4142    1.0000
```

But I just want to compute distance of the point image(3,2), so the function give me 1.4142

any function can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find row and column indices for all `1's`, then use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) from `Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox` to calculate distances for all `1's` from the search point `(3,2)` and finally choose the minimum of those distances to get the final output. Here's the implementation shown as a sample run -

```
>> image
image =
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     0
>> point
point =
     3     2
>> [R,C] = find(image);
>> min(pdist2([R C],point))
ans =
       1.4142
```

If you don't have access to `pdist2`, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to replace it like so -

```
min(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,[R C],point).^2,2)))
```